# C++ STL : Vector syntax

Tags: c++, stl

In one of my practice problems I came across a vector declaration I do not understand. Can someone break this down for me? I am new to STL

```
vector<string, vector<string> > friends;
```

I understand multi-dimensional vectors like the definition below, but i struggle to understand how a vector definition of string, vector<> as mentioned above would be.

```
vector<vector<vector<int> > > V(M, vector<vector<int> >(M,vector<int>(M,0)));
```

Comment: `vector<string, vector<string> >` is not a thing. Maybe someone meant to write `map` (or `unordered_map`).

Comment: That first one looks like [a syntax error](https://ideone.com/zdi05r) to me. Did you mean map or pair?

Comment: I think it should be map and is probably a typo. That would make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness: `std::vector` does allow you to specify a second template parameter--but that second parameter is the type of the Allocator for the vector.

Specifying the Allocator can be useful when you want to take control over how the vector allocates space for the data it holds. For example, Howard Hinnant has written a  [short-allocator](http://howardhinnant.github.io/short_alloc.h) that you might find interesting.

But (crucial point) the second template parameter doesn't specify anything about the data being stored--rather it specifies how to allocate space to store the data.

Answer (score 1):

The STL container used should be map and not vector. Vector is probably a typo.